# Print Outside of Console using JAVA

Tags: java, c#, windows

I'm a beginner programmer. Sorry ahead of time if my question ends up sounding ridiculous, but I'd like to know if what I want to do is at all possible. If it is, please tell me the things that I would need to learn to do it.

I would like to write a Java Program that detects a combination of key inputs (on Windows) such as control + e and outputs an accented e into any program, particularly a word processor. Would this be possible to develop in Java? If not, will I have to create this program in c#?

Thanks ahead of time. I really am not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for input from the keyboard is certainly possible. 
Just open an `Inputstream` as so:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStream(System.in)));
```

then read what the `BufferedReader` gives you for example like this:

```
String line;
while(line = br.readLine() != "your code to stop the programm"){
}
```

then check if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> has been pressed 
and print out to another programm.

For now try to accomplish this and toy around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will show the use of Robot class to handle the keyboard events. If you run this code and open a notepad then this code will write hi budy in the notepad.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotExp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

  Robot robot = new Robot();
     // Creates the delay of 5 sec so that you can open notepad before
     // Robot start writting
  robot.delay(5000);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);

} 
catch (AWTException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```